# HTML to Python - data is seen as string rather than list - how to force Python to process as multi-dimensional list

Tags: javascript, json, html, python-2.7, flask

I am formatting table data in HTML and sending it to Python using this script:

```
var html_table_data = "";  
var bRowStarted = true;
var count1 = 1

$('#woTable tbody>tr').each(function () { 

if (count1 != 1) {  
    html_table_data += "['"; 
}

else

    html_table_data += "[";

$('td', this).each(function () {

if (html_table_data.length == 0 || bRowStarted == true) {  

    html_table_data += $(this).text();  
    bRowStarted = false;  
}  

else  

    html_table_data += "', '" + $(this).text();  
});  

if (count1 != 1) {

    html_table_data += "'], "; 

}

count1 ++
bRowStarted = true;

});  

html_table_data = html_table_data.slice(0, -2);   // remove comma and space I added above for last element

html_table_data += "]";    // finish off the list
alert(html_table_data);

$.ajax({
url: '/plan_update/',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify(html_table_data),
type: 'POST'
```

Python receives that data which looks like a well formatted list however using the code below it tries to process as string (character by character) rather than a multi-dimensional list with each line having 9 data elements. In the above I have replaced the comma between each line of data with a \n but still get the same result. In python I have tried without the literal_eval with similar results. 
The python code is:

```
plantable = json.loads(request.data)
for lines in plantable:   
    plantable2 = literal_eval(plantable)
    Time = (plantable2[4])
    Quantity = (plantable2[5])
    Reps = (plantable2[6])
    Rest = (plantable2[7])
    Seq = (plantable2[8])
```

Can you please provide some guidance on formatting the HTML data differently or processing the existing data in Python so I can process each line and data element within each line.
Obviously I'm a newby so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, I would do a `print type(plantable)` just to make sure that Python is parsing your data correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're building a string to look like JSON, rather than building an actual nested array object. Then you're sending it to the server and it's processing it as a string.

Instead, build the data structure in Javascript as the multi-dimensional array, like so:

```
var html_table_data = []
$('#woTable tbody>tr').each(function () {
    table_row_data = [];
    $('td', this).each(function () {
        table_row_data.push($(this).text());
    });
     if (table_row_data.length > 0) { // Only add a row if it's not empty
        html_table_data.push(table_row_data);
    }
});
```

Then you can send `html_table_data` using your AJAX request as-is (keep the `JSON.stringify`).

The Python code also needs to be changed. `literal_eval` should be removed. `json.loads()` already converts the data from the request into a usable Python structure, so `literal_eval` will fail.

JSON is meant to transfer objects as text strings. Use the tools to do that, rather than trying to build the strings from scratch. As you can see, it's a lot simpler and less painful.

Comment: Again, thank you for the help! So close but I'm still only processing 1 empty record however I do notice a , that the start of the html_table_data data as shown below, wondering if that could be throwing things off?

Comment: [[], [u' wo name5', u'Sticky_Tape_Catch_Behind_R-97.mp4', u' cat1', u' subcat1', u'200', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0'], [u' test1', u'https://youtu.be/P-61-sgSN3w', u' testcat1', u' testsubcat1', u'20', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0'], [u' egsegege', u'Outside_Pull_Outside_Pull-59.mp4', u' fgsedsefgs', u' segsegse', u'1', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0'], [u'pdf', u'HTML-Cheat-Sheet_1.pdf', u'pdf cat', u'pdf sub cat', u'20', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0'], [u'pdf', u'HTML-Cheat-Sheet_2.pdf', u'pdf cat', u'pdf sub cat', u'20', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0']]

Comment: I'd have a look at the source code to the page. It may just have an empty row. It's hard to tell without seeing the input data (if possible, I'd suggest putting it in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com) and linking it. Likewise for the output data, it doesn't format well in comments. If it is an empty row, I've made a slight modification in my answer to skip it.

Comment: made the suggested change (modified to:  if (table_row_data != null){ // Only add a row if it's not empty
        html_table_data.push(table_row_data);
  })      but got same leading comma at start of data  - I also tried to add the Gist - please see comment at bottom of thread - Thanks for the help

Comment: You can put a Gist URL in plain to get a link: https://gist.github.com/glennf2017/71dea83efce5d246f5973258cfd10478

Comment: I updated the if statement (was thinking in Python, not Javascript). I ran my updated code against the data in the gist and it ran fine, returning one nested list in Python. I don't see any extra comma anywhere. Also worth noting your gist only has one table row in it, as it's not fully rendered, just the Jinja2 template.

Comment: thank you again for the help - I get a malformed string  error - this is the data from the flash:   [[u' wo name5', u'Sticky_Tape_Catch_Behind_R-97.mp4', u' cat1', u' subcat1', u'200', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0'], [u' test1', u'https://youtu.be/P-61-sgSN3w', u' testcat1', u' testsubcat1', u'20', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0'], [u'pdf', u'HTML-Cheat-Sheet_1.pdf', u'pdf cat', u'pdf sub cat', u'20', u'0', u'1', u'0', u'0']]  for the 3 lines of data -  the python is    plantable=json.loads(request.data)
flash(plantable)
try:  for line in plantable:   plantable2 = literal_eval(line)   Time = (plantable2[4])

Comment: I tried without the plantable2 = literal_eval(line) and get list index out of range  -- Again thank you for the help!

Comment: It works! took out the literal_eval and corrected the fact that it was using Time as a variable (a reserved Python keyword I assume, I shroud have thought of that) THANK YOU for the help! I up arrowed you but am too low in stackoverflow status for it to show apparently - I hope my sincere thanks is understood

Comment: Thanks. If that fixed things, be sure to mark my answer as accepted (checkmark). I'll update it with what you discovered about your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors here.

1. You are already creating json string in your JS. When calling `JSON.stringify` you're "double jsoning" thing, so remove `JSON.stringify`
2. As you're sending content type to be `application/json`, flasks `request` have `json` property

So, your ajax should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/plan_update/',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: html_table_data,
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST'
});
```

And python code should be like:

```
import json

plantable = json.loads(request.json)
for line in plantable:
...
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply - thank you - I made the changes but the same result - not very elegant but I flashed the data being passed - I enclose all the lines in a [ and ] - I have tried with and without, same result - does this data look properly formatted to be processed as a multi-dimensional list in Python? If so, then any idea why it would still be processing one character at a time rather than a line at a time?

Comment: [[' wo name5', 'Sticky_Tape_Catch_Behind_R-97.mp4', ' cat1', ' subcat1', '200', '0', '1', '0', '0'],[' test1', 'https://youtu.be/P-61-sgSN3w', ' testcat1', ' testsubcat1', '20', '0', '1', '0', '0'],[' egsegege', 'Outside_Pull_Outside_Pull-59.mp4', ' fgsedsefgs', ' segsegse', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'],['pdf', 'HTML-Cheat-Sheet_1.pdf', 'pdf cat', 'pdf sub cat', '20', '0', '1', '0', '0'],['pdf', 'HTML-Cheat-Sheet_2.pdf', 'pdf cat', 'pdf sub cat', '20', '0', '1', '0', '0']]

Comment: Can you add HTML also?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot one important thing in Python. Changed it.

Comment: added the link for the Gist but when I click it there seems to be a mess - when I look at directly it's clean so I'm clearly not using that tool correctly, one more thing to learn!

Comment: So here is the HTML for the entire table:<table id="woTable" style="width:100%" class="plantable">
    <tr>
     <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Workout Name</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Link</th>      
     <th onclick="sortTable(2)">Cat</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(3)">SubCat</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(4)">Time</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(5)">Quantity</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(6)">Reps</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(7)">Rest</th>
     <th onclick="sortTable(8)">Seq</th>
    </tr>

Comment: Can't add all the HTML because of comment limits but this is the section that has the data in it - just has 6 additional columns:<tr>
                               {% if planworow.plan_selected == planworow.plan_name %}
     <td style="background-color:yellow;" value="{{planworow.workout_name}}">{{planworow.workout_name}}</td>
     <td style="background-color:yellow;" value="{{planworow.workout_link}}" onclick="showlink">{{planworow.workout_link}}</td>     
     <td style="background-color:yellow;" value="{{planworow.workout_owner_cat}}">{{planworow.workout_owner_cat}}</td>

Comment: I'll give your edited suggestion a try as well  - thank you